# Would it be possible to have a utopia with an impenetrable shield around it?

Tags: technology

I would like to build a virtual world that has strict immigration policies with an impenetrable invisible shield around it. Sort of like Wakanda or like in that Wonder Woman movie.

Immigration is based on the peacefulness of the human aura. Immigration would be based on recruitment, since I wouldn’t want anyone who is unwelcome to find out about it. So it has to have a way to get in and out without being seen. If anyone accidentally stumbles on it, there has to be a detection device.

Deportation is based on if the peacefulness of the human aura— if it is lowered for a prolonged period and a person is unable to be rehabilitated through peaceful conflict resolution, or peaceful meditation. History of planet earth and current events are available for research so that anyone struggling with peaceful resolution is told: “you are free to leave”.  So planet earth is considered a sort of prison planet and an incentive or motivation for people to work on keeping it peaceful.

Shield and aura reader has to be unhackable so that some psychopath tyrant doesn’t get in there and start designing ‘rules for thee and not for me’. Of course there are other considerations about how it would be run and what the rules would be. Those would be issues for another time.

My main questions for now is, if anyone has ideas on what kind of technology would work for my shield and human aura reader? I’m thinking I could either hide the entrance in a remote place or put the entrance in plain sight. I know that invisibility shields are a real technology, but ideas about the impenetrability part would be helpful— what should it be made of? Rock? I’m not sure if it should be made out of something that requires a lot of work like mining because I’m trying to base my world on sustainability and living with natural environment. But am open to ideas.

For the aura reader I know there is Kirlian photography. Or Maybe it should be some sort of brainwave pattern reader or vibration reader instead. Maybe I need either a gate that does that when the person goes through it or a hand held device for my recruiters?

I’m sure there will also be some comments about some dystopian flaw too, so feel free to comment on that as well. But my main questions are: location ideas (remote or in plain sight), impenetrability material, and aura reader ideas.

**Question: is it possible to prevent immigration using an invisible and impenetrable shield ?**

Comment: “you are free to leave” - but not forcibly deported?

Comment: If you can build it, you can break it.

Comment: Can you make it extra clear: is the whole world virtual? If so, why adhere to all real world rules?

Comment: It seems like you're asking a lot of different questions. We have a one question per post limit Can you [edit] your post so that you are asking a single specific answerable question?

Comment: @simmy I focused your question on immigration and the "impenetrable and invisible" shield. I only added the question in bold. If you don't like the edit, put it back.. but close votes are piling up.. the question really needs to be focused more, there are too many questions now.

Comment: Your description of life inside the shield severely strains the definition of uropia.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are on the right track as far as your aura reader device. There are ways that people have claimed science as grounds for... um, certain choices (ie, eugenics, phrenology, etc.) A sufficiently advanced civilization, more so than ours, might even have some extensive grounds on which to segregate individuals based on peaceful temperament. I think this could be done most interestingly by avoiding it be complete mind reading - making it up to interpretation what analysis might mean makes it much more morally in question.

The society based around peacefulness idea reminds me a lot of Brandon Sanderson's Skyward series. The main character Spensa is a very intense girl who struggles a lot with how others perceive her. You might perhaps look at it for inspiration (and because it's a good sci fi).

As far as the shielding, you said this was Earth? Perhaps this hard stance on peace came about from a brutal war in the past. As part of this war, large battle stations were built in space. Now that those times are far distant memories, the battle stations have been retrofitted to blast anyone that tries to threaten their "utopia."

Energy shields are of course, a staple of sci fi, or at least, science fantasy. If you want to lend realism to them, add the need for large energy sources, or at least other limitations. Perhaps The shields cannot cover all of the planet, and entry points are tightly controlled.

There are a lot of ways that you could take this story - such places as a tightly guarded patch of space lend themselves well to prison breakout or heist stories.

And yes, I am among those that finds the idea of a complete utopia - or even a complete *dys*topia very unlikely.

Comment: The only problem with "eugenics" is the morallity of that practice.

Comment: @Edrel von Mises um.... eugenics was based not just off of a flawed moral stance, but also inaccurate views of science. If they'd actually been seeking scientific fact, they wouldn't have practiced eugenics.

Comment: @Edrel Von Mises wrong mankind has been pracpracticing Eugenics successfully for thousands of years literally for thousands of years if it is not scientific fact nothing is.

Answer (score 2):

## It's automatic.

This is in some circles known as a *passive restriction* or the *Alcobaça trick*, from the monastery where the refectory door was so thin, that glutton monks could not pass through, thereby being forced to fast and repentance. It was once employed in some kind of software security, intentionally designed with specific fragilities so that an attempt to circumvent security would have catastrophic results (imagine a jail where prisoners are fitted with pacemakers, and the controlling mechanism is the same that controls the door locks. Picking the locks is possible, but literally suicidal).

> a virtual world that has strict immigration policies

The virtual world needs to connect to the immigrant's mind - actually, *that* is how you "immigrate".

And the kernel of the virtual world connection engine is designed to interface with specific neurosomatic and mental responses, and *relies* on the assumption that there are no conflicting mental constructs.

As soon as the person is no longer "in tune" with the virtual world, they automatically expel themselves. To remain connected, they have to remain compatible.

It's sort of a passenger system where you hang by your hands throughout the travel. How do you make it so anyone unable to hold themselves for the whole travel is automatically expelled and killed? You need no sophisticated hand-grip strength monitor: you simply remove the bottom from the carriage.

Answer (score 2):

**Virtual rules and security**

A virtual world can follow virtual rules. This means that you don't need to adhere to any rules set in the real world. This goes much further than you think. A computer doesn't mind more than 3 dimensions. If you can somehow add more dimensions that it can calculate, it'll happily calculate what happens.

This is incredibly powerful. It can be done in ways that we can still make clear to the human mind, but it can also be mind bending and illogical from a human perspective.

An example. You have a door. If you walk around it, it takes exactly one step. If you go through it, it takes ten steps and looks like a tunnel. You arrive at the same space. The spaces change, yet look normal if you're walking through/around it. You can reverse this. Outside it looks like a tunnel, inside a doorframe. You can twist it so suddenly you're upside down. You can add more doors and have one arrive at another. The doors help us understand, but we can remove the doors altogether. Then you can even walk on an empty space and suddenly be transported upside down to a different area.

The above can be understood, but computers can make this illogical and unable to understand from a human perspective. Furthermore you can do this based on properties. For me it's a door as I'm not peaceful enough, but for my brother it's a tunnel. That can be your door.

But you can have the door in any dimension. Being peaceful can be interpreted as a dimension, so moving to an acceptable amount of peacefulness for a certain amount of time, like walking enough steps through the tunnel, and you'll arrive at the utopia. The door can then only appear the moment you're peaceful enough, making hacking very difficult as it's not in existence unless you're peaceful enough. With virtualisation you can make a door only appear for an individual, making it even harder to know about and hack the door.

**Security**

As mentioned above, knowledge of the door can be hidden. If no one knows about it, hacking becomes very difficult. With virtualisation you can make the door practically only accessible to the individual going through. Each individual can have a different form of door. Each door is in a different calculated dimension we don't understand or can even perceive.

The above should make it virtually impossible to hack it. Fully impossible is a fools errand, as anything can be hacked. Security is in most cases increasing difficulty and time. The best security depends on taking too long tong hack, even for the best expert, and requiring the most expensive equipment to do so. Lastly, the best security is difficult to see.

**Detection**

The detection can be done virtually in any way you want. As it's virtual, we can assume we have a ton of data. From the raw brain data to simply what this person is thinking about. I mean Google can determine for a large part of the population with great accuracy whether someone is pregnant, is gay, wants a new toy or whatever. They know a scary amount if stuff just from how you use the Internet. Imagine what you'll know when you can track their virtualised being every step of the way.

**Utopia location**

Your utopia doesn't need a shield or be invisible. As it's a virtual world, you can place it anywhere. Technically it can be a second Earth occupying the exact same space, only on a different plane. Best to separate them with an infinite space though, to make it as unlikely as possible that anyone arrives there by accident or on purpose.

**Utopia itself**

"'It's not their fault that the world is full of hard choices and hunger and loneliness', she said. 'What can you expect of people when demons are their neighbours?" *Name of the wind, Partick Rothfuss*

The above quote is a way how you can perceive your world. It can be difficult to live peaceful if all good people have gone. Only violent people stay behind. This makes it more likely that violence is a trait required to survive this world. How can you still go to utopia? How can you keep people in line? Better to keep adding people to utopia and virtually prevent them from doing harm. Any punch against someone else will have no effect for example. It's a virtual world, you can tinker with it. This way, with social inclusion and correction, more and more people will fit in.

Answer (score 0):

## Just check the Matrix's log files

You did say that is a virtual world. Thus it just be as easy like a spetial function of the Matrix that allows for this to happen.

## Make it so that the Matrix does no allow it to be penetrable

Normally it would be the case that there is no impenetrable thing, but the Matrix allow for it. Just set the entrance as impenetrable in the Matrix's configuration files.

Comment: Here, have your red pill.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi How I know it is no a blue pill?

Comment: Ummm... err... it won't help with sexual disfunction and the next thing you know is that you'll find yourself with tubes in you spinal cord? ;)